# Complex type for editorfor not posting values

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**I have following chtml**

```
@model Licensure.Business.Survey.Survey
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{

@Html.EditorForModel()  

}
```

I created following editorfor template for complex type

```
@model Licensure.Business.Survey.Survey
<div>

    <div class="container">


            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Sections.Count; i++)
            {             
               @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Sections[i])         
            }

            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SurveyId)

        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Save Survey" /> 

    </div>
</div>
```

Following is how I am creating complex type object

```
   var survey = new Survey() {
                    Name = "Survey for Testing",
                    Sections = new List<Section>()
                };

                var section = new List<Section>();

                var section1 = new Section() {
                    Name = "Section A",
                    ElementType = ElementType.Section,
                    Elements = new List<Element>(),
                    FieldAssemblyName = section.GetType().Assembly.FullName,
                    FieldClassName = section.GetType().FullName 
                };

                var section2 = new Section()
                {
                    Name = "Section B",
                    ElementType = ElementType.Section,
                    Elements = new List<Element>(),
                    FieldAssemblyName = section.GetType().Assembly.FullName,
                    FieldClassName = section.GetType().FullName 
                };

                var Question1 = new QuestionYesNo() {
                    QuestionText = "Do you like apples?",
                    ElementType = ElementType.AnswerableQuestion,
                    Id = 1
                };

                var Question2 = new QuestionYesNo()
                {
                    QuestionText = "Do you like getting hit in the face?",
                    ElementType = ElementType.AnswerableQuestion,
                    Id = 2
                };

                var Question3 = new QuestionMultipleSelect()
                {
                    QuestionText = "Do you like getting hit in the face?",
                    ElementType = ElementType.AnswerableQuestion,
                    Options = new List<QuestionOption>(),
                    Answers = new List<QuestionOption>(),
                    ToolTip = new QuestionToolTip(){Text="You need more info?"},
                    Id = 3
                };

                var Question3Options = new List<QuestionOption>();
                Question3Options.Add(new QuestionOption(){ DisplayText = "Option 1", Value = "1"});
                Question3Options.Add(new QuestionOption() { DisplayText = "Option 3", Value = "2" });
                Question3Options.Add(new QuestionOption() { DisplayText = "Option 4", Value = "3" });
                Question3Options.Add(new QuestionOption() { DisplayText = "Option 5", Value = "4" });
                Question3Options.Add(new QuestionOption() { DisplayText = "Option 5", Value = "5" });

                Question3.Options = Question3Options;

                section1.Elements.Add(Question1);
                section2.Elements.Add(Question2);
                section2.Elements.Add(Question3);

                survey.Sections.Add(section1);
                survey.Sections.Add(section2);

                return View(survey);




       public ActionResult Index(Survey model)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
```

Its displaying the question fine but when I am trying to post the values to controller its giving null for elements object, though I am able to get values of Section but null value for elements in model

[image]

Can somebody please help me here for how can I get posted values of each element which has different types of questions in it.

Comment: Do you have an `EditorTemplate` for typeof `Section`? What html is `@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Sections[i])` generating?

Comment: I have editortemplate for typeof Survey where I have for loop for section. Different types of questions are being generate like checkbox, radiobutton or dropdownlist depending upon element

Comment: You need to show the relevant code. All you have shown is a completely irrelevant block of code showing how you populate a `Section` (delete it!). Show your models and the view. If `Elements` is `null` its because you have an error in your model definition or in the view

Comment: On second thoughts, don't delete that code block yet - it appears that `Element` is a base class and your trying to add derived types (`QuestionYesNo` and `QuestionMultipleSelect`) to `List<Element>()` Unless you have a custom `ModelBinder` this will not work.

Comment: Yes, you are right Stephen, I tried custom model binder also, but its also returning no value for elements, can you please send me code for custom model binder. Thanks

Comment: I have just remembered your other question that I commented on. If you want to get started with creating an abstract `ModelBinder`, I suggest you start with [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx) but its complex and gets even more so when it involves properties which are collections. If you are prepared to group your questions in the view (i.e. all 'Yes/No' questions, then all 'Multiple Choice' etc) this can be solved easily with a view model and you can get rid of those ridiculous properties like `ElementType`, `FieldAssemblyName` and `FieldClassName`

Comment: Thanks Stephen, can you please send me example of view model you are suggesting.

Comment: Can't do without seeing your existing models, but your `Survey` view model would contain a property for `List<Section>` and the `Section` view model would contain properties for `List<QuestionYesNo>` and `List<QuestionMultipleSelect>` so that you are working with concrete types (no custom `ModelBinders` required). The only limitation is that the questions will be grouped by their type - i.e. display all 'Yes/No' for a section, followed all 'Multiple Choice' questions for the section.